# Number of sequences that satisfy the absolute difference condition

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, trees, dynamic-programming

Let  $x_0 =0$ and let  $x_1,.....x_{10}$ satisfy that $|x_i - x_{i-1}|$ = 1 for 1≤i≤10 and $x_{10} = 4$
. How many such sequences are there satisfying these conditions?

I tried to calculate it by backtracking from $x_0$ and $x_{10}$, and built an entire tree for the possible values. Based on the edges of the trees, I calculated the answer to be $2*4*6*7*7*7*7*6*4*2$ but the answer is clearly wrong. The question is supposed to be a probability question, but I was thinking of trying to solve it using dynamic programming. It is supposed to be an easy question though, can anyone help me out?

Comment: This problem is very much related to the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number). The answers are already quite sufficient, but you might find the Catalan numbers interesting to read about. Part of what makes them interesting is how many seemingly distinct representations they admit.

Comment: Thankyou! I will look into them.

Answer (score 8):

$x_i$ is either $x_{i - 1} + 1$ or $x_{i - 1} - 1$, right?

Then this is equivalent to you perform $+1$ or $-1$ by $10$ times, and expecting a result of $4$.

Simple calculation: If we choose to $+1$ by $x$ times, then $-1$ should be $(10 - x)$ times, and the result is $x \cdot (+1) + (10 - x) \cdot (-1) = 2 x - 10$, to ensure this equal to $4$, we must have $x = 7$.

Then the problem is to choose $7$ positions among $10$, and assign them to be $+1$, the rest $3$ positions are assigned by $-1$.

The answer is $\dbinom{10}{7} = 120$.

Answer (score 4):

> Let  $x_0 =0$ and let  $x_1,.....x_{10}$ satisfy that $|x_i - x_{i-1}|$ = 1 for 1≤i≤10 and $x_{10} = 4$

Alternative approach: 
nowhere near as elegant as the response of PinkRabbit.

From the problem constraints, you have that for $~i \in \{0,1,2,\cdots,8\},~$ that $~x_{i+2} - x_i \in \{-2,0,2\}.~$

Further, as $~x_i~$ goes to $~x_{i+2},~$ there is exactly 1 way that $~x_{i+2} - x_i = 2,~$ (i.e. $~x_{i+1} - x_1 = 1 = x_{i+2} - x_{i+1}~$) exactly 1 way that $~x_{i+2} - x_i = -2,~$ and exactly 2 ways that $~x_{i+2} - x_i = 0.$

Let

- $~y_1 = x_2 - x_0.$
- $~y_2 = x_4 - x_2.$
- $~y_3 = x_6 - x_4.$
- $~y_4 = x_8 - x_6.$
- $~y_5 = x_{10} - x_8.$

Then, examine each element (i.e. solution) in the collection of solutions to:

- $~y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 4,~$
- For $~i \in \{1,2,3,4,5\}, ~y_i \in \{0,-2,2\}.$

For each such solution, if exactly $~k~$ of the variables are equal to $~0,~$ then attach a weight of $~2^k~$ to that solution.  This corresponds to there being exactly two ways of achieving $~x_{i+2} = x_i.~$

It is immediate that none of the solutions can have all $~5~$ of the variables equal to $~0.~$   Also, because there are $~5~$ variables involved, and the sum is $~4,~$ the number of variables equal to $~0~$ **must be odd**.

Therefore, each satisfying solution will have either exactly 1 of the variables equal to $~0,~$ or exactly $~3~$ of the  variables equal to $~0.~$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 1: Exactly} ~1 ~\text{variable} ~= 0}$

There are $~\displaystyle\binom{5}{1}~$ choices for the variable equal to $~0.~$  Then, since $~3~$ of the $~4~$ remaining variables must be equal to $~+2,~$ rather than $~-2,~$ there are then $~\displaystyle\binom{4}{1}~$ choices for the variable equal to $~-2.~$

Therefore, the enumeration for Case 1 is

$$5 \times 4 \times 2^1 = 40.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Case 2: Exactly} ~3 ~\text{variables} ~= 0}$

There are $~\displaystyle \binom{5}{3}~$ choices for the $~3~$ variables equal to $~0.~$ Once these variables are set, the other two variables must each be set to $~+2.~$

Therefore, the enumeration for Case 2 is

$$\binom{5}{3} \times 2^3 = 80.$$

---

$\underline{\text{Final Computation}}$

$$40 + 80 = 120.$$

Comment: Conforting that the two answers agree.